confusion regarding calculation of coefficients in a 3rd order FIR filter
I am going through example 9 of chapter 6 of
A. V. Oppenheim and R. W. Schaffer, "Discrete-Time Signal Processing", 3rd Edition, Prentice Hall
I performed the calculations my self on my copy and i am getting answer 1.89 but here on book it is written as 0.795
I have also attached relevant snaps of book




I think there's a sign error in the book: $\alpha_2^{(3)}$ should be $-0.64$. With that sign change you obtain the same result as in the book.
